# What are the minimum permissions required to search or query Active Directory for Users, Groups and Group Membership?

Tags: search, permissions, active-directory, active-directory-group, activedirectorymembership

I have been able to enumerate Users, Groups and Group Members in Active Directory when I am logged in Administrator or Domain User in C#.

I would like to know which type of Users can read/query/search Active Directory objects.
Do we need to make the user a member of a particular Group or Assign permissions to the user ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need administrator or any permission to query/search/read AD group membership.  unless you have altered the default security. A normal user account should work fine, and user at least have the same group memberships. you can query your AD with no problems with a user account, you can run **CMD** or **Powershell** with the credentials of the user account and test some LDAP queries.

You can Follow this [Document](https://theitbros.com/ldap-query-examples-active-directory/) for LDAP query example.

> **Note**: One of the advantages of Microsoft's Active Directory is that it
> allows users to search objects in the database by performing
> Lightweight Directory Access Protocol queries. LDAP is an industry
> standard used by several directory services to access information
> within the directory database. Microsoft's Active Directory supports
> both LDAP versions 2 and 3

Referennce :https://mcpmag.com/articles/2006/09/18/searching-active-directory-objects.aspx.